# How to disable vim setting being overrode by plugins?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have `set paste` in /etc/vim/vimrc, but this setting is overrode by certain plugins which I don't know. When I paste from system clipboard, it will be formated automatically by certain plugins.
I'd like to make `set paste` to be global and constant. How can I make it without the need to know which plugin override it. Because I don't want to check it one by one when I add new plugins. Thanks!

Comment: `:verbose set paste` will tell you what module last set that option. Also see http://peox.net/articles/vimconfig.html

Comment: @ElizabethMyers  Thanks, that a good idea

Comment: 1. Having `set paste` by default is a *very* bad idea, if only because of all of its side effects. Use `"*y` or `"+y` or, if you can't get your hands on a proper Vim, use `:help pastetoggle`. 2. Putting your settings in `/etc/vim/vimrc` is another bad idea. Use `$HOME/.vimrc` instead.

Comment: @romainl Thank you, I think it's better to get accustomed to "+y  for becoming a good vimmer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that set `au BufWinEnter ?* set paste` in vimrc can make `set paste` option seems to be global and constant. But as @romainl said, this may be a bad idea because it will produce side effects on certain plugins. Either map `"+p` to `<C-v>` or get used to `"+p` is better than set it to be "global and constant".